# Converting from String to DateTime via parse exact failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to convert String (further divided by substring) to DateTime.  However the first part of the variable works but for the second part the output is a bit funny.

The value for `admissionDischargeDT` is `12/30/2016 12:00 am - 12/30/2016 11:59 pm`

> ```
> admissionDT:12/30/2016 12:00 am
> admissionDTInput:{30/12/2016 12:00:00 AM}
>
> dischargeDT:12/30/2016 11:59 pm 
> dischargeDTInput: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
> ```

The error message displayed is

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```c#
string admissionDischargeDT = adDT.Text;
string admissionDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(0,19);
string dischargeDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(21,20);

DateTime admissionDTinput = DateTime.ParseExact(admissionDT,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dischargeDTinput = DateTime.ParseExact(dischargeDT, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing logic for the second value is incorrect. It should be:

```
string dischargeDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(22, 19);
```

Comment: It Works!! Thank you!!